# Spark Executors & Tasks

Tags: apache-spark, architecture, internals

In Spark, an executor may run many tasks concurrently maybe 2 or 5 or 6 .

How Spark figures out (or calculate) the number of tasks to be run in the same executor concurrently i.e how many tasks can run in an executor concurrently?

An executor may be executing one task but one more task maybe be placed to run concurrently on same executor? What's the criteria for that?

An executor is assigned a fixed number of cores & memory. As we do not specify memory & cores requirements for task in Spark, how to calculate how many can run concurrently in an executor?

Answer (score 2):

Please find the answers below:

1. You cannot control tasks memory and cores in Spark.
2. Number of executors is managed by Spark and can be set only when YARN is used as the cluster manager.
3. What do you mean by using static variables. I guess the intent is sharing variables between different tasks. In the Spark execution engine, this can be achieved using [accumulators or broadcast variables](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#shared-variables).
4. Each task is run as a process thread in executor JVM. Tasks from different applications run in different JVM.
5. Yes, the number of tasks spawned depends on the number of partitions in your RDD. That is why for performance gain we suggest to play with the **coalesce/repartition** functions in spark.
6. RDDs are not mapped to executors. Multiple partitions from an RDD may be served by multiple tasks which may belong to multiple executors.

You can have a brief look at the cluster overview of Spark [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html).

Comment: spark.task.cpus = Number of cores to allocate for each task. So you can kinda control number of cores per task

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Few more questions. Let's take a scenario where we are running single job. Will tasks run concurrently or they would run sequentially? If concurrently, how many tasks would run in an executor (how spark would calculate number of tasks that can run in an executor)? How much memory & cores get allocated to a task?

Comment: The tasks are part of stages and stages run sequentially. Two or more tasks of same stage may run concurrently across multiple executors for parallel computation computing the same logic. The SparkContext within the driver program controls and sends the tasks to the executors. Have a look at the Spark Job Scheduling here http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html.

Comment: @shekhar Yes you are right. Task cores can be controlled.

Comment: ok, thanks again. If tasks of same stage can run concurrently, how Spark would calculate how many tasks of the same stage need to be executed in a single executor? There should be some logic like total Executor memory = 64 GB, task memory = 1 GB so total number of tasks maybe 64. I need to know this info in order to calculate heap size consumption by task.

Comment: because a task does nothing but just processes an RDD partition. And, it's pretty fine for tasks to be executed in parallel. But question is how many would be executed in parallel in a single executor? Because heap size & memory of executor would be shared between tasks. And, to be sure tasks does not go out of memory we should know how many tasks  can run in an executor?

Comment: Primarily tasks spawned in a stage will be equal to the number of RDD partitions.

Comment: If these answer to your questions, please accept my answer above. Thanks.

Comment: thanks a lot but I wonder how Spark would calculate the number of tasks (of same job & of same stage) that can run in an executor?

Comment: @Raj number of tasks in a stage = number of partitions in the RDD

Comment: Maybe I am not able to frame the question properly. Let me do it again. An executor may run many tasks concurrently maybe 2 or 5 or 6 . How Spark figures out (or calculate) the number of tasks to be run in the same executor concurrently i.e how many tasks can run in an executor concurrently? An executor may be executing one task but one more task maybe be placed to run concurrently on same executor? what's the criteria for that? An executor has fixed number of chores & memory. As we do not specify memory & chores requirements for task in Spark, how to calculate how many can run concurrently?